# Using pyOpenSSL, can you extend the expiration of an existing self-signed certificate?

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, tls1.2, pyopenssl

What I am trying to do:

- If a certificate already exists in a specified directory, "clone" it but extend the expiration (not after) date.

My questions:

- Do I need to do this process manually? Get all fields, extensions, attributes, etc, from the existing file and generate a new certificate with this info, then delete the old version?
- Is there a method in this library to do this that I'm not seeing?
- Do I need to generate a new private key when I do this, or will the existing key work with a new cert file?

Comment: I don't know about pyOpenSSL, but the openssl cli itself is able [to perform this conversion](https://serverfault.com/a/1010313/27515). You could look at that code and implement the same thing in Python. You can use the same private key with any number of certificates.